# How do you get mysql to connect to a website (created using html and css)

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, xampp

I am a student who needs help with some coding. My assignment requires me to create a website that uses mysql database with xampp to store, retrieve and create reviews for games. Is there a way to connect mysql to my website *WITHOUT USING PHP*. Our assignment specifications dictate that we can't use php so I'm looking for alternatives. All help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You need a server side language to connect. You can use node for example

Comment: Wierd assignment specifications... Because you can't connect MySQL by only using html, css and javascript (in browser).. Unless you use Node.js which is a server based javascript framework which can connect to MySQL.. Or use other programming lauguages like python (py), Java server pages (jsp) or Active server pages (asp)

Comment: Can you store a basket inside an apple? You can connect to a database from a website, but you can't connect a website from a database.

Comment: Just to be clear, mysql doesn't connect to an application, but the application connects to the mysql database. What your assignment is wanting you to do is to experiment with different server side languages, such as asp.net or ruby as a couple of examples.

Comment: Jmango, what server-side language are you supposed to use?

Comment: I think my teacher hinted that we didn't need any other languages so I'm suspecting that we are supposed to use java script since html and css are out. We were given files called "dB-connection.js" and "server.js" but we were not really told what they were.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to use the browsers IndexDB, you cant accomplish this. Html is a markup language and CSS are the styles rendered to HTML, they cant connect with MySQL db or any db in that regard. You need a server language to connect with the database. Other alternatives to php are Node JS, Python etc..